# Obtain text between p tags within only certain span IDs with DOMdocument or SimpleDOM?

Tags: php, parsing, plaintext

I am trying to pull plaintext between `<p>` tags but only if between 
    `span id='a' and span id='b'.`
SimpleDOM seems to work, and I've yet to find a way to coax DOMDocument to produce any output at all.

Comment: clarify your question please. show some input and the desired output and anything you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();   
@$doc->loadHTML($html);   
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);  
$elements = $xpath->query("//*/p/span[@id='a']");
```